# class instance per request in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new with asp.net mvc. I have an app class which only needs one instance per request. It has IDispose so i'll need it to be dispose properly and I call it every page hit.

The problem I am finding is I sometimes needs to call methods in my view. I have no idea how I can access the class in the controller, view and have it dispose properly at the end of each request. I get the feeling I need to replace ALL of my controllers with my own controller class as a base. But this would only work if it executes the view first and I can access members in MyController from the view (actually I can just stuff it into the viewbag can't I)

Whats the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I have never found the need to access "methods" in the view from the controller. I don't have any methods in the view to access. I can't help but think that you may be approaching your problem the wrong way around.

Comment: The controller creates the model. The controller creates the view and passes in the model. The view renders the model. There should be no logic in the view other than how to render the model.

Comment: @ColinMackay: Hmm. Then replace view with code ran on every pagehit of every controller. It seems kind of wrong I need to replace the default `: Controller` to my own controller and have heavy code run in the constructor.

Comment: Lets say every page my master view shows the toolbar and if the user is logged in. I need to check if the user is logged in every page hit. I had a Api.IsLoggedIn() in my master.cshtml file. I guess i just set a bunch of variables instead in the viewbag and I need to do that logic in MyController constructor and have every controller inherit that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to wire up a Dependency Injection framework (such as Ninject) and let it control the object lifetime for you.  Ninject has a InRequestScope lifetime policy, which will create one object per request, so subsequent calls to get the object will return the same object if it is in the same request.

Comment: How does it know when the request is over?

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the dependency injection you can dispose your dependencies or objects like below in the controller.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)

    {
    _requestRepository.Dispose();
    base.Disposing(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to do this for EVERY CONTROLLER? I mean... well it looks like visual studios autogen it to use controller which looks like its defined in a reference. Rather then a MyController. Is there no way to add members to every controller somehow or have it generate the rest of the controllers as mycontroller?

Comment: Yes.the object destroys when the request is complete. Please make sure that the base class or interface must implement the IDisposable interface.

Comment: You can dispose dependencies only from the controller.